# Which voice is better here, passive or active?

Tags: passive-voice

Between

> If the moral principle of “love your neighbour” is adhered to, then the world will be free of war.

and

> If we adhere to the moral principle of “love your neighbour”, then the world will be free of war.

Which fits better for formal writing? For me, the structure of the first sentence is worse, because its use of the passive voice is unnecessary.

Comment: Off topic writing advice request. You might try [writers.se].

Comment: Apart from the voice, note that the first version does not specify **who** is to adhere to, so there's a semantic difference, sometimes a convenient escape-route! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could equally well say that the ***we*** in the second sentence is unnecessary since the sentence as a whole is clearly about people or humanity in general.

Which sentence is more appropriate for your context depends on your main focus. In the first sentence (first clause) *the moral principle of “love your neighbour”* is the subject (or theme or topic) of the clause. In the second sentence the subject is *we*.

If the focus of your preceding text has been on the '*love your neighbour*' principle or moral principles in general, then the first sentence is preferable.

If, on the other hand, the focus of the preceding text has been on the different things that we or humanity can do to make the world a better place, then the second sentence is better.

Answer (score 2):

The passive voice best conveys the meaning here.  In the second sentence, *we* implies that only the speaker and listener(s) need love their neighbours for the desired result, whereas the first sentence implies a broader scope.

Something to remember is that the passive voice is not always bad.  Unnecessary use is 'John was run over by a bus', for 'a bus ran John over' conveys the information more directly.  In the examples that you gave, however, the information is conveyed quite directly, regardless of the voice used.  Unnecessary use would be 'If the moral principle of "love your neighbour" is adhered to *by you and me*'.